# Deserializing json value where attribute has ":"

Tags: c#, json, c#-2.0

I am using a REST service and it returns json formatted like this:

```
{
"ea:productionId": "123",
....
}
```

How can I create a class at server side corresponding to this type of json for parsing? I am using c#.

**EDIT**
 I am using **C#2.0**
This is the code I am using

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        JsonClass result= serializer.Deserialize<JsonClass>(jsonresult);
```

JsonClass is the class I have created with the fields corresponding to the attributes in the jsonresult.
And the problem is, I can't create a property with name `ea:productionId` as it contains `:`.

Comment: Did you try `result['ea:productionId']`?

Comment: @jan - that's the way to do it.

Comment: `{ ea:productionId: "123" }` is invalid JSON. `{
"ea:productionId": "123" }` (note extra quotes) is valid. Was that an error or is the web service response really broken?

Comment: Your last question is a little bit unspecified.

Comment: It is valid. I suppose it is just copy paste from browser. It will be only invalid to assign it without qoutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown in your question is invalid JSON. I guess you meant this:

```
{
    "ea:productionId": "123",
    ....
}
```

which is pretty easy to achieve with [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) serializer using [`[DataContract]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`[DataMember]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes on your model:

```
[DataContract]
public class JsonClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "ea:productionId")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
JsonClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonresult);
```

If you don't want to use third party JSON serializers you could use the built-in [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class which also respects the DataContract and DataMember attributes:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonClass));
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonresult);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    var result = (JsonClass)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you are using .NET 2.0 and cannot rely on the newer serializers. With the JavaScriptSerializer you have the possibility to write a custom converter:

```
public class MyJavaScriptConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    private static readonly Type[] supportedTypes = new[] { typeof(JsonClass) };

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return supportedTypes; }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (type == typeof(JsonClass))
        {
            var result = new JsonClass();
            object productId;
            if (dictionary.TryGetValue("ea:productionId", out productId))
            {
                result.ProductId = serializer.ConvertToType<string>(productId);
            }

            ... so on for the other properties

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new MyJavaScriptConverter() });
var result = serializer.Deserialize<JsonClass>(jsonresult);
```

alternatively you could use a weakly typed dictionary instead of the model:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var res = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonresult);
string productId = res["ea:productionId"] as string;
```

Comment: `private static readonly Type[] supportedTypes = new[] { typeof(JsonClass) };` creates an error: `implicitly typed array cant be used`

Answer (score 0):

json is actually similar to a dictionary(key-value pairs) in python. You cannot write your key without quotes. Your key should actually be a string via which you can refer its values. Yours is invalid json.

Try this :

```
{
"ea:productionId": "123",
....
}
```

OR you can try this also(assuming your's is a dictionary inside a dictionary)

```
{
"ea":{"productionId": "123",}
....
}
```

So to have an access to value "123" , use `["ea"]["productionId"]`